# Why don't C# interpolated strings accept variable padding?

Tags: c#

C# interpolated strings allow one to add left or right padding to strings. Depending on what you're outputting, you might need to adjust the level of padding. Why does C# have a problem with using a variable to denote the padding? (Please see example below.)

```
public static void example(string name, ApplicationCall NxRequest)
{
    // Both 'headers' and 'values' are string arrays.
    var headers = NxRequest.Headers();
    var values = NxRequest.Values();

    // I want to set the level of padding based on the maximum length 
    // in the 'headers' string array.
    var padding = headers.Select(x => x.Length).Max();
    const int constPadding = headers.Select(x => x.Length).Max();

    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
    {
        // This works.
        Console.WriteLine($"{headers[i].ToUpper().PadRight(padding)} {values[i]}");

        // This doesn't work because constPadding cannot be set as a constant.
        Console.WriteLine($"{headers[i].ToUpper(), constPadding} {values[i]}");
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I introduced a better example.

Comment: Here's a question for you to answer: Suppose we have `String.Format("Hello {0,12}", someNumber)`.  Why can we not put an arbitrary variable in for `0` or `12`? By figuring out the answer to this question, you will deduce the answer to your question.

Comment: Hint: Plainly C# must compile `$"{item, -12}"` to some more fundamental code. *Exactly* what more fundamental code does it translate it to?

Comment: @EricLippert it probably translates to `String.Format`. How many muffins do I win?

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks for your insight, but I think my original example was an oversimplification. I edited to add a more complicated example.

Comment: Your improved example does not change the fact that you have not answered my question. **Why can we not put an arbitrary variable into the format string in a call to `Format`**? You've asked a vague "why" question; by answering an equally vague but more fundamental "why" question, you'll get the insight you need to understand this design decision.

Comment: When people ask "why" questions about language design decisions it is difficult to know what will satisfy them; much of the time, the "why" question is really "how can I make this code work?" Sometimes it is "which section of the specification controls this behaviour?" Sometimes it is "what was the psychological process in the minds of the dozen people who were in the language design meeting that day?"  -- That's a hard one to answer. And sometimes it is just complaining. My advice is that you ask a question that begins with "what" or "how" if you want a satisfying answer.

Comment: @EricLippert, I think `$"{item, 12}"` compiles to `String.Format("{0, 12}", item)`. My understanding is that an arbitrary value cannot be passed into the padding because then integers would be used for both the values as well as the padding. And it wouldn't be clear if some integers were meant to represent a placeholder for a variable, or if they were a padding value.

Comment: @EricLippert I can already do this in C#? https://dotnetfiddle.net/W1RZ0c

Comment: @NechemiaHoffmann: Your sample code is `Format("{0,"+p+"}", "*")`.  The original poster is essentially asking why they cannot write `Format("{0,p}", "*")`, and avoid the string concatenation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to make pad a constant:

```
foreach (var item in new string[] { "cat", "dog", "mouse" })
{
    const int pad = -12;
    Console.WriteLine($"{item, pad}");
}
```

If a constant cannot be used, then you must use a [string padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) function, such as PadLeft, or PadRight.

Comment: Maybe remove the "this does not work" comment since you are showing what works...

Comment: Done -- Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: While this fixes the issue directly, from the context I think we are meant to assume that pad is changed or calculated on each iteration.

Comment: @MichaelG, thanks but my original example was an oversimplification. I introduced a better example, and I don't see how using the `const` keyword can help me here...

Comment: @N4v - It's not possible without a constant value.  You'll need to use Pad[Left|Right]()

Comment: @MichaelG, please add your comment to your answer so I can accept as the correct answer.